# Correlation between two vectors vs. angle between vectors

Tags: matlab, math, vector, correlation

I am trying to determine if the movement of two objects is "in phase" or opposing each other. So basically I have two vectors, R1, R2 in R^3 and I want to know if they "point in the same direction".

I can think of two ways to compute that:
a) Calculate the angle between the two vectors. The angle indicates their alignment. 
b) Calculate the correlation coefficient between the two vectors. (e.g. using Matlab's corr function) 1 means they are parallel, -1 antiparallel. If they are perpendicular I do get either plus or minus 0.5, which seems wrong.

Is there a difference in using the two methodologies? My gut feeling says that the two methods should be identical, but I am not sure. Anyone has some insights and what could be potential differences/advantages of the methods?
Thanks!

Comment: The correlation is related to the cosine of the angle, for details see [this](http://www.the-idea-shop.com/article/221/a-more-elegant-view-of-the-correlation-coefficient).

Answer (score 1):

This is most easily done by calculating the dot product between the two normalized vectors. The inverse cosine gives directly the angle between the vectors.

Matlab doesn't have a "corr" function. It has "xcorr". The cross correlation between two 3 element vectors is a 5 element vector. The middle element of that is the same as the dot product, so it's basically the same calculation.

Comment: Matlab has `corr` function in Statistcs Toolbox. It returns correlation coefficient (linear or ranked).

Comment: sorry if my question sounds stupid, but which of the 5 elements of xcorr should I consider? Only the middle element? I am tempted to use the angle between vectors, as it seems a more intuitive measure to correlation.