# Difference between two vectors

Tags: math, similarity

How can I measure the difference/similarity of two vectors?

That is...Let us suppose that I have two vectors in R^3:
v1 = {1,8,3}
v2 = {2,5,10}
Let us consider that v1 and v2 are representing directions.

I would like to measure how much v1 and v2 are pointing to the same direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correlation between two vectors vs. angle between vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570724/correlation-between-two-vectors-vs-angle-between-vectors)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different "similarity" measures between vectors, but one of the more popular ones is [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), i.e. the cosine of the angle between them.

This measure is convenient because it will give a number between -1 and 1, where 0 means that the vectors are perpendicular, 1 means that the vectors point in exactly the same direction, and -1 means that the vectors are diametrically opposed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I forgot to mention that I would like to find a measure tht is able to capture the fact that an angle of 180 degrees would produce the maximum difference. I have found the cosine similarity, but it seems that this measure assumes that maximaly different vectors have 90 degress between them.

Comment: @Zaratruta Actually looking closer at it, cosine difference can still do that if you don't take the absolute value. -1 is diametrically opposed, 0 is perpendicular, 1 is same direction.

Comment: So...If I want a measure whose maximum difference is when the angle between the vectors is 180 degrees, and normalized between 0 and 1, I can normalize the result of the cosine, doing
(cosine(v1,v2)+1)/2.
Is it correct?